# Find a view at specific location in swift

Tags: swift

I have got a simple view in swift and put 9 buttons as a 3x3 grid onto it, now i need the tag for each button and don't know how to get each button so I can get the tag property using a for loop. Does anyone know how i can get the button? Is there a function to get a view at a specified location?

Comment: Each view has a `tag` property that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Frankenstein's answer with `.subviews` works fine, but you can even do it more *swifter* using the built-in function `viewWithTag(_:)`:

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // ...

        // targeted view must have been added to the subview by now
        if let taggedView = view.viewWithTag(1) {
            print("Got the view!")
        }

        // you can even try to cast directly
        if let taggedButton = view.viewWithTag(1) as? UIButton {
            print("Got the button!")
        }

        // if you insist on using a for loop, you could use it like this
        let highestTag = 10
        for i in 0...highestTag {
            if let taggedButton = view.viewWithTag(i) as? UIButton {
                // here you go
            }
        }
    }
```

For both approaches keep in mind, that the view you're looking for **has already been added as a subview** beforehand, otherwise you won't be able to search for it

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `subviews` property of `UIView` and loop through each subview to check for `tag` you need:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for subview in view.subviews {
            if subview.tag == 1, let button = subview as? UIButton {
                print("Got the button I need.")
            }
        }

        if let button = view.viewWithTag(1) as? UIButton {
            print("Got the button I need.")
        }
    }
}
```

Update: You can also use `viewWithTag` to find you view with a particular tag from within your subviews.